# Likelihood between two functions

Tags: estimation, curve-fitting

I have a function $f(x)$ describing a physical process, and a function $g(x)$ that tries to approximate it. I can clearly see by eye when the two functions are close enough, but I would like a mathematical tool to do it in a reproducible way.

For now, I am using as a figure of merit $\int_0^b \left | f(x) - g(x) \right | dx$, where $b$ is chosen suitably (my functions are even, positive and are equal to 1 apart from a small area around the origin). The result is normalised to $\int_0^b \left | f(x) - 1 \right | dx$. My -arbitrary- level of acceptance is when this value is equal to 0.05.

Unfortunately this procedure doesn't agree well with what my eye would the me. For example these two functions:

[image: $f(x)$ in blue and $g_1(x)$ in yellow. $\Gamma_1 = 1$, $\Gamma_2 = 0.508$, $s=0.01$]

are considered "alike" ($f(x)$ in blue and $g_1(x)$ in yellow. $\Gamma_1 = 1$, $\Gamma_2 = 0.508$, $s=0.01$), while these two:

[image: $f(x)$ in blue and $g_2(x)$ in yellow. $\Gamma_1 = 1$, $\Gamma_2 = 1.5$, $s=0.01$]

are not ($f(x)$ in blue and $g_2(x)$ in yellow. $\Gamma_1 = 1$, $\Gamma_2 = 1.5$, $s=0.01$). I have read of some other methods to estimate the likelihood between two functions, but couldn't find a suitable one. I guess an ideal method would be a measure of my procedure mixed with a measure of the distance between the curves in every point, but I haven't found anything like it.

For completeness, the function $f(x)$ I'm using is:

$f(x) = 1 - \frac{\eta + \mu}{2\mu} e^{(-\eta+\mu) |x|} - \frac{-\eta + \mu}{2\mu}e^{(-\eta-\mu) |x|}$

where $\eta=-\frac{\Gamma_1 + \Gamma_2}{2}$ and $\mu=\sqrt{\frac{(\Gamma_1 - \Gamma_2)^2}{4} - s \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2}$. The two functions I am comparing it to are $g_1 (x) = 1 - e^{-\frac{\Gamma_1 + \Gamma_2}{2} |x|} \left ( \cos ( \sqrt{s \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2} |x|) + \frac{\Gamma_1 + \Gamma_2}{2\sqrt{s \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2}} \sin ( \sqrt{s \Gamma_1 \Gamma_2} |x|) \right )$ and $g_2 (x) = \left ( 1-e^{-\frac{\Gamma_1}{2}|x|} \right )^2$. The only constraints on the parameter are $s>0$, $\Gamma_1>0$ and $\Gamma_2>\Gamma_1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as these are empirical distributions, you should aim to use the `ks.test` function in R. It is the Kolomogrov-Smirnov test and it can be used to measure the distance between two curves, namely the Empirical Distribution Function of the sample and a reference Cumulative Distribution Function. It is a measure of distance by measuring for a difference in location and shape, which seem appropriate in this case. It may be a little more sensitive compared to the eyeball test, but it is not nearly as sensitive as Anderson Darling and Shapiro Wilks tests. To use the KS test, it is simply `ks.test(fx, gx)` can can be used for two sample tests.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I had actually seen this test, but I was put off by the fact that they seem to work for probability distributions. I am comparing two functions depending on time. Would that still work? In principle, I could build an histogram from them, and then compare them, but seems a bit involved...

Comment: @SamueleGrandi I see your conundrum. Here is the link to another similar question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/760819/is-there-any-statistical-method-to-compare-two-curves . I thought these were to gamma distributions, not to arbitrary functions.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. The answer in the link you provided is the same procedure we are using at the moment. It has some issues, but overall it's a good measure. Thanks again!